# my program is not reading my text file?

Tags: java

I made a method to get grab the most repeated words of an array. In the main method, i use the Scanner class to read through my file. My file is the star spangled banner lyrics. I then scanned the file and assigned its value to a string. Then i split the string and assigned it into an array. When i instantiate the mostRepeated method For some reason i always get "file not found"? I dont understand whats wrong with the code? please help, thanks !

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Task2Ref23 {
    public static String mostRepeated(String [] a){
        int count=1, tempCount=1;
        String temp="";
        String popular = a[0];
        for (int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++){
            temp=a[i];
            if(temp==a[i+1]) tempCount++;
            else if (tempCount > count){
                popular=temp;
                count= tempCount;
                tempCount=1;
            }
        } if (tempCount > count) popular = temp;
        return popular;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Erik Landaverde
        String temp= "";
        try{ 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("lyricFile"));
            while (scan.hasNext()){ 
                temp= scan.next();
            }
            String [] myArray=temp.split(" ");
            String mostRepeated = mostRepeated(myArray);
            System.out.print(mostRepeated + " ");
            scan.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){ 
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing .txt after your file. Try lyricFile.txt (or whatever kind of file it is) and see if it runs

Comment: I'm not seeing how the FileNotFoundException could be thrown within mostRepeated(), as you don't ever interact with a file. You should double check your trace. One thing I can think of is that you don't have any path specified on your file, so your IDE is likely looking somewhere inside your project files for the file, and your file is likely in the wrong spot or somewhere else on your computer. You should try looking up where your ide looks for files, or specify an exact path. I would also suggest @TheJavaKing's answer

Comment: Post your full stack trace.

Comment: the path you posted for file belongs to folders under `src` of your application and If this is the file, must place extension and you can see inside your project structure **directly** if any above said is wrong then you need to think that what are you actually doing

Comment: `while (scan.hasNext()) { temp= scan.next(); }` That loop reads and throws away all the data in the file except the last token.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```html
Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("lyricFile.txt"));
```

Or if it's not a .txt file, the correct extension, instead of what you have

Comment: I tried adding the .txt but i still get the same message. I created a folder just so the Class and the lyricFile are there. Then nothing. Then i created a package and moved the class and lyricFile there aswell and still. The file "lyricFile" i created it within the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

**"File not found"** message gives due to the file does not exist in the file system. I noticed that in you given code, if the "lyricFile" file is not exist then it will throw FileNotFoundException exception. In catch section you added to print the out put you getting.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("lyricFile"));
```

Exception handling part in your code

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e){ 
    System.out.println("File not found.");
}
```

So you may need to update your code as below to create new file if the file is not available.

```
    File file=new File("lyricFile");
    //Check whether file not exist then it will create the file
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (file);
```

Note that you need to add catch section for IOException.